# linear regression on 8D X data returns nan

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am trying to run linear regression on data with shapes (768, 8) and (768,) for X and Y respectively. I want to run the predictor such that I get values for y for the last three rows of X. I have manually added content of one row to the predictor.

```
class LinearRegression() : 
      
    def __init__( self, learning_rate, iterations ) : 
          
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate 
          
        self.iterations = iterations 
          
              
    def fit( self, X, Y ) : 
          
        self.m, self.n = X.shape 
          
        # weight initialization 
          
        self.W = np.zeros( self.n ) 
          
        self.b = 0
          
        self.X = X 
          
        self.Y = Y 
                  
        for i in range( self.iterations ) : 
              
            self.update_weights() 
              
        return self
      
    def update_weights( self ) : 
             
        Y_pred = self.predict( self.X ) 
          
        # calculate gradients   
      
        dW = - ( 2 * ( self.X.T ).dot( self.Y - Y_pred )  ) / self.m 
       
        db = - 2 * np.sum( self.Y - Y_pred ) / self.m  
          
        # update weights 
      
        self.W = self.W - self.learning_rate * dW 
      
        self.b = self.b - self.learning_rate * db 
          
        return self
      
    def predict( self, X ) : 
        return X.dot( self.W ) + self.b
```

```
def runLR() : 
    X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(  
      X, Y, test_size = 1/3, random_state = 0 ) 
    model = LinearRegression( iterations = 1000, learning_rate = 0.01 ) 
    model.fit( X_train, Y_train ) 
    see = model.predict(np.array([[0.98, 514.5, 294.0, 110.25, 7.0, 2.0, 
    0.0, 0.0]]))
    print(see)
    
runLR()
```

However, the result of `see` that I get is
`[nan]`. I believe I am passing my data into model.predict in a wrong format?

Comment: I expect there to be a nan in at least one of your weights, you could print them in your train loop to see how they change and if/when something goes wrong. This can in turn be caused by a nan in your data, have you checked for that?

Comment: Btw, why are you using gradient descent for LR? You can calculate the optimal weights in one simple step.

Answer (score 0):

```
X=np.random.normal(size=(768,8))

Y=X[:,0]+2*X[:,1]+3*X[:,2]+4*X[:,3]+5*X[:,4]+6*X[:,5]+7*X[:,6]+8*X[:,7]

def runLR() : 
    X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(  
      X, Y, test_size = float(1)/3, random_state = 0 )

    model = LinearRegression( iterations = 1000, learning_rate = 0.01 ) 
    model.fit( X_train, Y_train )
    print(model.b)
    print(model.W)
    see = model.predict(np.array([[0.98, 514.5, 294.0, 110.25, 7.0, 2.0, 
    0.0, 0.0]]))
    print(see)
    
runLR()
```

This should work. Just change 1/3 to `float(1)/3` in the test_size because 1/3 is just 0 I think.

```
-1.2610015928318272e-07 #b is about 0
[0.99999993 1.99999988 3.00000005 3.99999998 5.00000002 5.99999999
 7.00000003 7.99999991] # W is 1 through 8
[2399.97995156] # predicted y
```

To add more predictors, add them to the array like this: `np.array([[0.98, 514.5, 294.0, 110.25, 7.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0],[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2],[5,6,7,8,1,2,4,3]])`

Comment: `1/3 == 0` would only be the case for python 2.x. I wouldn't assume the cause of the problem is the use of very old versions.

Comment: Changed the test_size but it still gives me nan with my current X,Y data :(

Comment: yeah that's probably not the problem @GillesOttervanger